# common terms in two sequences .

Tags: sequences-and-series

In my book there is a solved question . [image]

In that question I could not understand from where does $(3\lambda + 2)$ come from

And is there any other method to solve it

Comment: It seems to come from $T_n=3n-2$ so I think it should be $3\lambda -2$, but not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

If $3n-2=7m+2$, then adding $5$ to both sides

$$
3(n+1)=7(m+1)
$$

Hence $3|(m+1)$ so that $m=3\lambda +2$ for some integer $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Your objective here is to figure out where the terms of both sequences are the same. In general you do this by expressing one variable (n) in terms of the other (m) and then expressing both in terms of a third variable (λ). This way you can see which terms in Tn are the same as which terms in Tm, just by plugging in successive values of λ.

In your example n = (7m + 4)/3

Because n can only be an integer, we know that 7m + 4 must be some integer multiple of 3. Thus:

7m + 4

Must be of the form:

3(a + b) = 3a +3b

So m must:
-Be composed of a variable that when multiplied by 7 gives a multiple of 3
-Be composed of a constant that when multiplied by 7 and added to 4 gives a multiple of 3

It's natural then to say m = 3λ + 2.